# Get filepath to LocalDB file from connection string in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, connection-string, filepath, localdb

How to get the filepath to the `.mdf` file of a `LocalDB` database from its connection string in .NET?

**Example string:**

```
Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDb.mdf
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string GetFilePathFromConnectionString(string connectionString)
{
    var attachDbFileName = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString).AttachDBFilename;
    return attachDbFileName.Replace("|DataDirectory|", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString());
}
```